# How to receive message posted in the iframe to an ssr react app

Tags: reactjs, iframe, server-side-rendering

am trying to post a message into the domain which is a server side rendering react app. after posting the message I cannot receive the message in the server side

Though I can able to post the message, in server side rendering I could not access the window. Is there any fix for this

```
const attributes = {
    src: "demo.com",
    width: "100%",
    height: "175",
    frameBorder: 1, // show frame border just for fun...
};


const postMessageData = "hello iframe";

const onReceiveMessage = () => {
    console.log("onReceiveMessage");
};

const onReady = () => {
    console.log("onReady");
};

return (
    <IframeComm
        attributes={attributes}
        postMessageData={postMessageData}
        handleReady={onReady}
        handleReceiveMessage={onReceiveMessage}
    />
);
```

Parent App:
postMessageData = {Data}

I need to get this post message in the domain which am integrating using  iframe